# Unsual working of Date() method in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, date, methods, invalidation

```js
const mydate = new Date('2023,1,18');
console.log(mydate.toDateString());
```

This code results in

> `Wed Jan 18 2023`

whereas

```js
const mydate = new Date(2023, 0, 18);
console.log(mydate.toDateString());
```

also gives an output

> `Wed Jan 18 2023`

But

```js
const mydate = new Date('2023,0,18');
console.log(mydate.toDateString());
```

is invalid for this case why?